# When I(root) excute "usermod -G sudo chauncey",it say that "sudo group doesn't exist"

Tags: linux

OS: CentOS 7. When I (root) execute the command below, it says that "sudo" group cannot be found.

```
[root@localhost etc]# usermod -G sudo chauncey
usermod：“sudo” group doesn't exits
```

I also check file in `/etc/group`, and "sudo" doesn't exists in it. So, how can I create a "sudo" group correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the `groupadd` command...

Comment: Did you install the package sudo? The install script should create the group.

Comment: @KarstenKoop it should be installed..because when type "sudo",it can show it's usage.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a group called sudo? You don't need it to use sudo command.

Comment: @Vinicius In my linux system has a user----chauncey,and I want to add chauncey in *sudo* group,but *sudo* group can't find.

Comment: Yes, but you **do not need** to create this group. If you want to give sudo powers to a user you have to edit /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: you are right,and i unstand that is sudoers file make it works and no need to create "sudo" goup manual. But I confused that sometime in some linux distributions that have *sudo* group in /etc/group file ,after excuted " usermod -G sudo test_user" , and the *test_user* has sudo privilage.I want to know how it works and what relations between /etc/group-->sudo and sudoers file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sudo is not directly a group. The groups/users having sudoer rights are defined in a configuration file that you can access using `sudo visudo`.  Check out this file to find out how it is configured on your system. Here is a good introduction https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html.

In your case, you have different ways to give sudo rights to *chauncey*.

1. find the group(s) having sudo rights in the sudoers file and add *chauncey* to one of these groups. For example, say you have this line in sudoers:

   ```
   # Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
   %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
   ```

   then, add *chauncey* to admin with `sudo usermod -a -G admin chauncey`.
2. create a new `sudo` group (`sudo groupadd sudo`) and add this lines (`sudo visudo`). Then once again add *chauncey* to the group

   ```
   # the 'sudo' group has all the sudo privileges
   %sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```
3. set a special rule for this user in the sudoers file using the following (note that there is no `%`, which is used to denote a group):

   ```
   chauncey    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

Note that for all the rules I mentioned, I used the default `ALL` everywhere. The first one is the user(s) allowed, the second one is the host, the third one is the user as you are running the command and the last one is the commands allowed. You can tune your rules if ALL is too broad for your usecase.

Comment: thanks,I have a new understanding of the sudo command by reading that Hyperlink content.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped you. Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes,I have new understanding for "sudo".But I have some confuse.you can see my last comment to @Vinicius

Comment: In CentOS, do `wheel` instead of `sudo` ->
```usermod -aG wheel username```

Answer (score 22):

In centos, you adduser to wheel group instead of sudo.

`usermod - aG wheel username`